# Every field is an integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra

I don't know if it's late or I'm tired, but for some reason my following argument for proving every field is an integral domain seems wrong to me:

> Let $k$ be a field and $x,y \in k$. Assume that
>   $xy=0$. Then $$ x^{-1}xy=y=0=x=xyy^{-1}.$$

The reason I think my argument is wrong is that the conclusion I arrive to is $x=0$ and $y=0$, whereas the proper approach to proving this by the contrapositive is obtaining $x=0$ *or* $y=0$. Could someone highlight my mistake?

Comment: You are (i) correct that every field is an integral domain; but (ii) wrong in your argument. You can only get $x^{-1}$ if you assume $x\neq 0$; you can only get $y^{-1}$ if you assume $y\neq 0$. So correctly you would say “If $x\neq 0$, then...” and conclude $y=0$, in which case there is no $y^{-1}$ to perform the right side of your equality chain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are left-composing with $x^{-1}$, you are assuming that $x \neq 0$. The argument goes like this: you assume $x \neq 0$, and prove $y=0$. Also, you can assume $y \neq 0$ and prove $x=0$, by composition from right.

Answer (score 0):

In a field there is no zero divisor. If $xy=0$, then $0 = x^{-1} 0 = x^{-1}(xy) = (x^{-1}x)y = 1y = y$. Done.